# SqlCommand execution slower if Management Studio Query Window is not open

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I've been currently working on an application that is supposed to test certain scenarios while SQL Server is running, like for example, PC reset as if power went down.

The code is fairly simple, I declared a static class that contains the declaration of the SqlConnection:

```
public static void CreateConnection(string connectionString)
{
    connection = new SqlConnection (connectionString);
}
```

And two classes that both Open and Close the connection (closing irrelevant for this question but still inserted it for completion purposes):

```
public static void OpenConnection()
{
    if (connection == null) return;
    connection.Open ();
}

public static void CloseConnection()
{
    if (connection == null) return;
    connection.Close ();
}
```

The connectionString is nothing special either, just the Data Source, login and password, no more parameters set for that one.

So, the process of the application is the following.

1. Start app
2. Create Connection
3. Open Connection
4. Create Database if it does not exist
5. Create Table if it does not exist and add an index to a column
6. Start a Timer that executes a class that contains the INSERT statement
7. Execute closing app (irrelevant)
8. Closing event closes connection (irrelevant)
9. App got closed (irrelevant)

Sorry for step 7 through 9, couldn't resist inserting them.

The Timer that is executing that very INSERT statement is running it everytime in a 50ms interval, and of course, from step 3 through 6 never did I close the app or connection, I just let it be open.

Now here comes the strange behavior which I found interesting and I decided to ask here since I couldn't find anything online about it:
You can literally notice the stuttering in the counter I inserted on the GUI to track how fast it is being executed, example: 1 2 3 4 .. 5 6 7 8 .. 9 10 11 12....and so on, there is a visible stutter.

Now here comes the strange thing, as soon as I open Management Studio 2014, navigate to my Database and open the "New Query" window, the INSERT statement becomes blazing fast on my app!
What previously had stuttering was running like a Golf MK2 with 800 horsepower, absolutely fluid like I was expecting the moment I wrote it, no more stuttering like explained above.

And after I close Management Studio, it goes back to stuttering until I do the same process of getting into New Query again.
What could be the cause to it?

Oh, of course, here is my INSERT statement, sorry for the long read:

```
public static void InsertValues(string tableName, string dbName)
{
    string query = @"INSERT INTO " + dbName + ".dbo." + tableName + " VALUES ('" + Text + "','" + Date + "')";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand (query, connection)) {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this happen with a release build exe run from the shell?

Comment: Yep, also happens with Release.

Comment: Just some tips which probably are not relevant with your problem. Don't share one SqlConnection, use command parameters, there is no need to Dispose the SqlCommand.

Comment: Alright, noted.

Comment: Side note: Your sql statement is vulnerable to sql injection attacks, you should use parameterized queries. For more info see [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements). This **could** (but probably not in this case) also have an effect on performance though as each query plan is cached based on the text. With the statement above sql server would have a new plan for every combination of variables you use.

Comment: But it goes faster when I open a query window in Management Studio, the INSERT call is still being called like before Management Studio was opened.

Comment: What about the performance monitor in SSMS? Can you see anything of interest there (with a new query window and without)? What about closing SSMS while your app is running and at the point it was fast, does it then revert to being slow?

Comment: Are you logging the time taken to call command.ExecuteNonQuery ()?  You could time that using Stopwatch and log it to a file as you go.  I'm wondering if the SSMS windo is chatty with the server, and causes some link to be more quickly available.  BTW I wouldn't worry about learning to not dispose objects that implement IDisposable (such as command), it's much more important to make sure that you do dispose them if they require it - also some code metric checkers flag up objects not disposed.

Comment: Are you connecting to a `localdb` instance or to a remote server? Are you on a wired or a wireless connection?

Comment: I'm not logging times, I notices the difference in my app GUI since the numbering counted a lot faster when I had the query window open.

Comment: I'm connected to a localdb, app is running on the pc the SQL server is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the AUTO_CLOSE database option to OFF using the [ALTER DATABASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) statement. The effect you're seeing may be caused by the database being closed after execution of your command due to the connection being cleanly closed, making it necessary to fully reopen the entire database for the subsequent execution of the command. Opening a query window opens and maintains a connection, thus preventing the automatic closing of the entire database.

Comment: Seems like AUTO_CLOSE was the cause, is it actually good practice to set it to OFF?

Comment: Yes, as documented by Microsoft itself, for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb402929.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

because Management Studio and SqlConnection have different SET defaults , a these set commands are automatically run to set up the execution environment. SQL Profiler can be used to monitor which SET commands are issued by both SSMS and .NET so you can find other differences.
You can monitor the difference between these set commands by using Profiler.

You can try these [Set Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx) in your C# code like this and compare the results.

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cynic I managed to fix the stuttering by setting AUTO_CLOSE to OFF.
I used the following query in case somebody needs it in the future:

```
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachdb
'
IF (''?'' NOT IN (''master'', ''tempdb'', ''msdb'', ''model''))
   EXECUTE (''ALTER DATABASE [?] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF WITH NO_WAIT'')
'
```

Which I got from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic692557-149-1.aspx).

Of course I only did that because I had several DBs, if you only need to do that to a particular one:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
```